# Get data from MYSQL using PHP returns no results

Tags: php, mysql, undefined-index

So I am using this tutorial: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-mysql-tutorial-to-perform-basic-crud-operation/ to try and get data from my local MYSQL server (using Wamp64). I had the undefined index error at first, which I fixed using the isset() statement.
But now it just returns:

```
{"result":[]}
```

I have, however, a lot of data in the set column of that database.
Here is the code:

```
<?php
//Getting the requested klas
$klas = isset($_GET['klas']) ? $_GET['klas'] : '';

//Importing database
require_once('dbConnect.php');

//Creating SQL query with where clause to get a specific klas
$sql = "SELECT * FROM lessen WHERE klas='$klas'";

//Getting result
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

//Pushing result to an array
$result = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
    array_push($result,array(
    "id"=>$row['id'],
    "klas"=>$row['klas'],
    "dag"=>$row['dag'],
    "lesuur"=>$row['lesuur'],
    "les"=>$row['les'],
    "lokaal"=>$row['lokaal']
    ));
}

//Displaying the array in JSON format
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I tried out the

```
SELECT * FROM lessen WHERE klas='$klas'
```

statement in my database and it seems to return the correct data.
Any idea what is causing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you make sure that "klas" is set in the `$_GET` array? And you are open to SQL injection this way. Clean your input before putting it into the query.

Comment: use `$sql = 'SELECT * FROM lessen WHERE klas="'.$klas.'"';`

Comment: @ManjeetBarnala No improvement at all.

Comment: How do I check that? And I'll take a look into cleaning my input. I have no experience whatsoever in PHP.

Comment: Check variable $sql , Try echo $sql;  what is the output?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM lessen WHERE klas=''{"result":[]}` That's the output I got using echo $sql.

Comment: Run SELECT * FROM lessen WHERE klas='' QUERY DIRECTLY ON DATABASE

Comment: I did, and it returns data as normally requested.

Comment: check what you are getting in $row inside the while loop by printing it using print_r() or var_dump().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Point 1 is:**

`isset` function only checks if `klas` is set in the `$_GET` global array. So if somehow `$klas` is blank - your query will return empty (*without giving error*).

So please check values in the `$_GET` and possibly from where it is accessed. Or you can add condition to avoid empty query like --

```
if (!empty($_GET['klas'])) {
// rest of the code block upto return
```

**Point 2 is:**

You have mentioned if you echo the sql it returns

```
SELECT * FROM lessen WHERE klas=''{"result":[]}
```

Here the second part (*the JSON*) is from echoing the result at the end of your code. So for the first part (*i.e. echoing `$sql`*) we see that `klas=''`. That actually goes to the ***Point 1*** as mentioned above.

So finally you have to check why the value at `$_GET` is showing blank. That will solve your problem.

### UPDATE:

From @GeeSplit's comment  For the request

`"GET /JSON-parsing/getKlas.php?=3ECA"`

There will be nothing in `$_GET['klas']` cause the querystring in the url doesn't contain any key.

So either you have to change the source from where the file is called. Or you can change how you are getting the value of `klas`.

**Example**:

```
$tmpKlas = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$klas = ltrim($tmpKlas, '=');
```

Rest of your code will work.

Comment: I did have the code `$klas = $_GET['klas']` at first and it returned normal results for a couple of hours, but then it suddenly gave me the errors. I have no clue where to begin.

Comment: You can see the apache access log in WAMP. 
Suppose the name of your PHP file is `api.php`. Then the request will come to server as `..../api.php?klas=12315...`. So if klas is empty it will show something like `.../api.php?klas=`.

Comment: The log looks something like:  `127.0.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2016:16:00:57 +0600] "GET /api.php/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4120 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36"`

Comment: access.log gives me this when I reload the php page: `[06/Apr/2016:12:11:44 +0200] "GET /JSON-parsing/getKlas.php?=3ECA HTTP/1.1" 200 47`

Comment: So here is the issue. For the request `"GET /JSON-parsing/getKlas.php?=3ECA"` There will be nothing in `$_GET['klas']` cause the querystring in the url doesn't contain any key. Updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<?php
$klas ='';
if(isset($_GET['klas']) && !empty($_GET['klas']))
{
    $klas = $_GET['klas'];
    require_once('dbConnect.php');
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM lessen WHERE klas="'.$klas.'"';
    $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $result = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
        array_push($result,array(
        "id"=>$row['id'],
        "klas"=>$row['klas'],
        "dag"=>$row['dag'],
        "lesuur"=>$row['lesuur'],
        "les"=>$row['les'],
        "lokaal"=>$row['lokaal']
        ));
    }
    echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Comment: try to use a static value of `klas` in your query, and see if it return result

Comment: `'SELECT * FROM lessen WHERE klas="1"'` or any value of klas in your db table

Comment: `SELECT * FROM lessen WHERE klas = '3ECA' ` , which returns the results I need but do not get through with the PHP script.

Comment: you are getting `3ECA` in `$_GET['klas']` ??

Comment: Hold up, I did this in my php script: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM lessen WHERE klas='3ECA'";` and it returns the values I need.

Comment: this means that you have problem in `$_GET['klas']` and you are getting your variable `$klas` empty.

Comment: I have no idea how to fix this, because the same exact script worked yesterday for a couple of hours and then suddenly stopped working.